# Spring Security 3.2.0 Anonymous and Single Sign On - user remains anonymous

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

We have an application implemented with Spring Security 3.20 and CAS 3.5. Everything is working fine expect for the anonymous portion. If someone has logged into CAS, we would like them to show up in the application with their logged in username, but instead they show up as anonymousUser. This is only on pages that allow both anonymous or a logged in user. If they explicitly go to a page requiring a role, then the SSO on kicks in and they show up as whatever the logged in user is. What do we need to configure so that they show up as the logged in user without forcing them to go to a secure page (or is that the only way)?

Our configuration is as follows:

```
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/canary.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/test.html" access="hasRole('ADM')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/testAnon.html" access="hasRole('SEC') or isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/policySelect.html" access="hasRole('ADM')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('SEC') or isAnonymous()"  />
    <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/cas-logout.jsp"/>
    <custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/WEB-INF/jsp/403.jsp"/>
</http>
```

If someone is logged into CAS and goes to testAnon.html, they still show up and anonymous until they go to another page like test.html that requires the role of ADM. After that they are logged in and stay that way on all pages.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I've got a similar problem with Spring and CAS

Comment: I did not unfortunately. My client did some work-arounds that I didn't necessarily agree with to get around it.